# What are these schematic symbols in the HCPL3700? (square with arrows and overlapped circle)

Tags: schematics, symbol

I am working with [HCPL3700](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/149/HCPL3700-1010474.pdf) to sense mains.

In the [datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/149/HCPL3700-1010474.pdf) it has these symbols:

[image]

What are those symbols? What are their functions?

Comment: The overlapping circles are a current source. Partial duplicate: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/56670/2028

Comment: they are actually block diagram symbols ... they each represent multiple components

Comment: Thanks @jsotola! I was missing that and looking for one component for each :S

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The square with arrows is [hysteresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis#Electronic_circuits), as evidenced by some of the electrical characteristics of the device.

[image]

[image]

The overlapping circles are a [current source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_source).

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmitt_trigger

Comment: Thanks @Bort. That link made me understand! :)